# Convert android.support.v4.app.Fragment to regular android.app.Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

Quick question.

Is is possible to convert a Fragment from the support v4 library into a fragment of the regular app library?
If so, how?

I can't find any information online to do this. I hope its not a duplicate.

Comment: What are you actually trying to _do_?

Comment: Im trying to fit a ViewPager and PagerAdapter into a FragmentActivity that has an inner class of ActionBar.TabListener.
The problem is that I already have a fairly large and complex app made with regular fragments, so switching that to the support library is not really a easy task.

Comment: Why are you looking to use `FragmentActivity`? For that matter, why are you looking to use action bar tabs, since they have been deprecated in Android 5.0?

Comment: The truth about deprecation, for me at least with Android, is that 5.0 will take at least a full year before reaching 15% of the market share. Once we get there I'll worry about what works better for the application and the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are completely different and you can't convert from one to the other.

The [v13 Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v13) contains classes which use `android.app.Fragment` rather than support fragments. Specifically, the [android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) allows you to use regular fragments with a `ViewPager`.